# How to get tsc to Resolve Absolute Paths when Importing Modules using baseUrl?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc, tsconfig

Consider a simple typescript project with the following directory structure:

```
|   package.json
|   tsconfig.json
|               
\---src
    |   app.ts
    |   
    \---foobar
            Foo.ts
            Bar.ts
```

`tsconfig.json` has been configured to have `./src/` be the `baseUrl`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "baseUrl": "./src/"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Now suppose we want to import `Foo` in `Bar.ts`. My understanding is that by setting the `baseUrl`, we can now use absolute paths to import modules

```
import { Foo } from 'foobar/Foo'
```

as opposed to relative paths

```
import { Foo } from './Foo'
```

If my understanding is correct, the typescript compiler should be able to automatically resolve `foobar/Foo` to `./Foo` when compiling `Bar.ts`.

```
import { Foo } from 'foobar/Foo';

export class Bar {
  foo: Foo;

  constructor(num: number) {
    this.foo = new Foo(num);
  }
}
```

Running `tsc` compiles without errors. Yet, when we actually look at the compiled `Bar.js`, we would see that the path has not been resolved correctly, which would give us a *Cannot find module* error if we were to run it.

```
"use strict";
const Foo_1 = require("foobar/Foo");
class Bar {
    constructor(num) {
        this.foo = new Foo_1.Foo(num);
    }
}
exports.Bar = Bar;
```

**So my question is: How can I get `tsc` to correctly resolve the absolute paths when importing modules using `baseUrl`? Or if this is not something that can be done, what is the purpose of `baseUrl` then?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your module loader does not know how to find the module given the absolute path `foobar/Foo`.

The TypeScript compiler (tsc) is resolving the module paths correctly, otherwise you would get compilation errors. But it is trusting you to configure your module loader appropriately.

For example, from the [documentation for RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl):

> > Supported configuration options:
> >
> > baseUrl: the root path to use for all module lookups.

The TypeScript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url) talks a little about why you might need `baseUrl`:

> > Using a baseUrl is a common practice in applications using AMD module loaders where modules are “deployed” to a single folder at run-time. The sources of these modules can live in different directories, but a build script will put them all together.

Comment: Thanks! So in other words, `tsc` isn't responsible for converting absolute path to relative path, and I'm supposed to configure the module loader to resolve it instead? If that is the case, is there a way to get `tsc` to simply convert to relative path instead?

Comment: No, as far as I know, `tsc` won't convert paths for you. If possible, it will be easier to use paths in your `import` statement that conform to your module loader spec/config, and then use the various compiler options to tell `tsc` how to resolve the module names accordingly.

Comment: @Zsw As an alternative, checkout the "outFile" compiler option. It will concatenate the modules into a single output: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#concatenate-amd-and-system-modules-with---outfile

Comment: Hi there, I'm aware this question is a bit old, but how do you "know" which module for code generation you want ? I have the same problem but I want my output to be in another directory and conserving the original structure of the project.

Comment: You can use `NODE_PATH=dist/ node dist/app.js` so that node can also resolve absolute paths.

Comment: @DenisPshenov thanks for the tip, this is what solved the issue

Comment: @DenisPshenov Thank you! I can't believe the answer is buried in the comments.

Answer (score 21):

The answer comes from @DenisPshenov's comment in one of the answers. It's buried, so I'll provide it here...

Tell Node where the base url is with `NODE_PATH` environment variable so that it can resolve absolute paths:

**Linux / macOS**

```
NODE_PATH=dist/ node ./dist/index.js
```

**Windows Powershell**

```
$env:NODE_PATH="dist/"
node ./dist/index.js
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who is still struggling on this problem.

```bash
npm i -D tsc-alias
# pacakage.json#scripts
tsc && tsc-alias
```

Comment: This should be the best answer nowadays.
Very simple and it just works!

Comment: This is the only answer. I just spent two days of my life fighting the plugin. It shouldn't be this hard! There should be a simpler way! There isn't. Install `tsc-alias`.

Answer (score 2):

`tsc` cannot convert path to relative path although you config `baseUrl` and `paths`, `paths` is only useful when you are coding in editor to lint your code.
If you want it work, you can use ts-node and tsconfig-paths module:

```
$ yarn add ts-node tsconfig-paths --dev
```

And run this script

```
"start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register app.ts"
```

Then you can get the right perform.

Answer (score -1):

You can to that using tsconfig's `path`:

> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "baseUrl": "src",
>     "paths": {
>         "app/*": ["app/*"],
>         "config/*": ["app/_config/*"],
>         "environment/*": ["environments/*"],
>         "shared/*": ["app/_shared/*"],
>         "helpers/*": ["helpers/*"],
>         "tests/*": ["tests/*"]
>     },
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, you can tell the TypeScript file resolver to support a
> number of custom prefixes to find code. This pattern can be used to
> avoid long relative paths within your codebase.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig